# Duplicating a data structure with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, sizeof

I'm trying to duplicate my data structure that contains a pointer and a integer. But I'm not sure if it is the right way to do so.

Here is my structure:

```
struct sample_t {
    int x; 
    void *y;   
};
```

Here is my function:

```
struct sample_t *dup(struct sample_t *sample){

  struct sample_t *dup_sample = malloc(sizeof (sample));

  dup_sample->x = sample->x;

  dup_sample->y     = malloc(sizeof(sample->y));
  dup_sample->y     = sample->y

  return dup_sample;
}
```

Comment: Wrong.You are still copying the pointer *value* . Do you want a *deep* copy*?

Comment: The malloc uses the wrong size

Comment: but `sizeof(*y)` would  make no sense(and is forbidden) . Deep copy is impossible without knowing the object's size.

Comment: Since the field y of the `sample_t` struct is a `void*`, there's no way to tell how many bytes to allocate for it.  Your call to allocate space via: `malloc(sizeof(sample->y));` only allocates enough bytes to hold a pointer, and not the actual data that it points to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code copies the content of the structure pointed to `sample` to a newly allocated structure:

```
struct sample_t *dup(struct sample_t *sample) {
    struct sample_t *dup_sample = malloc(sizeof *sample);
    *dup_sample = *sample;
    return dup_sample;
}
```

Note that the memory you are allocating must have enough room for the data and must have the size of `*sample` (the structure), not the size of `sample` (an address).

As for the copy, a mere affectation `struct1 = struct2` is enough.